# Django Rest Framework + ReactJS: Whats wrong with my API?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to fetch data from a `django` rest-framework API, using `ReactJS' but I keep facing the same error:

> SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

I think the actual problem is is in my API, since I have already tried 3 different approaches to get the data into React. Maybe somebody knows what I can do to my API to make it work? Im using the `djangorestframework` library. The API looks as following:

```js
{
"questions":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/?format=json",
"choices":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/choices/?format=json"
}
```

And the `React` `Component` I'm using to retreive the data is the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ApiFetch extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('127.0.0.1:8000/api/?format=json');
      const data = await res.json();
      this.setState({
        data
      });
      console.log(this.state.data)  
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);  //SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {(this.state.data)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ApiFetch;
```

The Header of the API looks like that:

```html
allow →GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
content-length →123
content-type →application/json
date →Fri, 17 Aug 2018 11:01:36 GMT
server →WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.3
vary →Accept, Cookie
x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
```

I tried the following example API with my client and it worked: 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

So something about djangorestframework and my client must be incompatible.

Comment: Full response with response headers and request headers would be more helpful. @noel please attach them upon availability

Comment: The Response I was able to print in the console is the following. 

`code`Response
​
bodyUsed: true
​
headers: Headers
​​
<prototype>: HeadersPrototype { append: append(), delete: delete(), get: get(), … }
​
ok: true
​
redirected: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
type: "basic"
​
url: "http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:8000/api/?format=json"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … } `code`
Im not sure how to get the header, but my server logs this: 
`code`[17/Aug/2018 10:52:49] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 99`code`

Comment: DRF typically returns HTML content when you get an error server-side (404, 500...) which your client-side JSON then cannot parse, giving you the error message you're seeing. To help you debug, can you show the relevant parts of `url.py` and your `views.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: **needed to add Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)**

The Problem here was, that Browsers prevent Javascript from reaching out to other domains according to the *Same origin Policy*.

The default workaround for this in Django, is "django-cors-headers". 
To install it:

`pip install django-cors-headers`

Then it can be activated in the `settings.py`

Writing:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ##...
    'corsheaders'
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    #...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to query a valid route, perhaps try following:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/?format=json');
      const data = await res.json();
      this.setState({
        data
      });
      console.log(this.state.data)  
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);  //SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
    }
  }
```

Comment: The goal here is to get an javascript object looking like this: 

`code`
data = {
"questions":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/?format=json",
"choices":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/choices/?format=json"
}
`code`

Im trying to get it work with this more simple api first of all.

Comment: Can you console.log the res constant before you parse it to json??

Comment: It logs:

`code`Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:8000/api/?format=json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }`code`